# Cambiar base_url por ip de la computadora

Tags: codeigniter

Tengo un problema al cambiar la `base_url` de `CodeIgniter`, lo que hice fue sustituir `localhost/Taller/` por mi ip y la `xxx.xxx.x.xx/Taller/` en mi propia laptop si la acepta pero la quiero ver desde otra laptop y no puedo, no carga, pero tengo otro error si pongo `localhost/Taller/` en el navegador me la sigue aceptando cuando no debería porque la `base_url` ya la cambie.

**Configuración de CodeIgniter config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/Taller/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['encryption_key'] = '$%·%&/&(()/()/(¿?=¿=';
```

Estas son las únicas líneas de código que modifique

Comment: Podrías poner la configuración que tienes el el archivo config.php de codeigniter, el error puede estar por ahi.

Comment: Hola @Javier fr fijate en tu Firewall de Windows que estee desactivado y que todo este en la misma red

Comment: si dejen pongo mi configuracion de CodeIgniter